# NSString crash on release

Tags: objective-c, ios, memory-management, nsstring

Here is my `ItemInfo` class interface

```
@interface ItemInfo : NSObject {
    NSString *item;
}
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *ipaddress;
```

... and the implementation

```
@synthesize item;
- (id) initWithItem:(NSString *)someItem {
    self = [super init];
    if(self) {
        item = someItem;   // Ideally these things should happen here. 
                           // Since item is a NSString and not NSMutableString,
                           // it should be sent a retain, thus
                           // making its refcount = 1
                           // Is my understanding correct?
    }
    return self;
}

- (void) dealloc {
    [item release];   // I own 'item', so I should release it when done
    [super dealloc];
}
```

I am using this class from elsewhere like thus:

```
char *str = inet_ntoa(addy->sin_addr);
ItemInfo *h = [[ItemInfo alloc] initWithItem:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s", str]];
ContentBrowserViewController *d 
        = [[ContentBrowserViewController alloc] initWithItemInfo:h]; 
[self.navigationController pushViewController:d animated:YES];
[h release];
[d release];
```

The crash I am encountering is
`*** -[CFString release]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x6225570`. `0x6225570` is the address of `h.item`

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to call your setter using `self.item = someItem`. You currently disregard the setter and therefore do not copy/own the String.

Comment: Thanks much! I overlooked omitting `self.` disregards the setter.

Answer (score 3):

In your `initWithItem:`, you need to do `item = [someItem copy];` You *could* also do `item = [someItem retain];`, but that would cause problems if your string was a NSMutableString.

The reason for the crash is that you pass an autoreleased string, and your `initWithItem:` doesn't say *"I need this string to stay around"* (retain) or *"I need my personal version of this string"* (copy). The string thus gets released too often as you do release it in your dealloc.

According to your source, I'm willing to bet that the crash does not happen in the code you've posted but actually when the NSAutoreleasePool is finally releasing the string.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out I was not retaining / copying the object. I indeed had a copy setter defined, but was not using it as @marcus pointed out.